# I cant edit before decimal palces in between into input box once validation is fired in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have following input box in angular js

```
<div class="row">
    <div id="validationsummary" class="alert alert-danger" ng-show="hasError && msform.$invalid">
        <p style="text-align:left;"> Error : <br />  </p>
        <ul class="custom-error">
            <li ng-show="msform.preferenceOrder.$invalid && !msform.preferenceOrder.$error.min && !msform.preferenceOrder.$error.max && !msform.preferenceOrder.$error.pattern">
                <label for="preferenceOrder"><i class="fa-fw fa fa-times"></i>{{MessageConstant.formValidations.Supplier.InvalidpreferenceOrder}}</label>
            </li>
            <li ng-show="msform.preferenceOrder.$invalid && msform.preferenceOrder.$error.min">
                <label for="preferenceOrder"><i class="fa-fw fa fa-times"></i>{{MessageConstant.formValidations.Supplier.MinpreferenceOrder}}</label>
            </li>
            <li ng-show="msform.preferenceOrder.$invalid && msform.preferenceOrder.$error.max">
                <label for="preferenceOrder"><i class="fa-fw fa fa-times"></i>{{MessageConstant.formValidations.Supplier.MaxpreferenceOrder}}</label>
            </li>
            <li ng-show="msform.preferenceOrder.$invalid && msform.preferenceOrder.$error.pattern && (!msform.preferenceOrder.$error.min || !msform.preferenceOrder.$error.max)">
                <label for="preferenceOrder"><i class="fa-fw fa fa-times"></i>{{MessageConstant.formValidations.Supplier.DecimalPointpreferenceOrder}}</label>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <section class="col col-md-6" ng-class="{'has-error' :  ( hasError || msform.preferenceOrder.$error.pattern) &&     msform.preferenceOrder.$invalid }">
        <label class="label">Preferred Order</label>
        <ng-form name="preferenceOrder">
            <label class="input">
                <input type="number"
                       ng-pattern="DataConstants.FieldValidationPattern.decimalValueExpression"
                       max="999999999"
                       min="0.01"
                       onkeypress="return isNumber(event, this, 2)"
                       title="Preferred Order"
                       name="preferenceOrder"
                       id="preferenceOrder"
                       ng-model="Supplier.PreferenceOrder"
                       class="form-control"
                       placeholder="Enter Preferred Order" />
            </label>
        </ng-form>
    </section>
</div>
```

Now, when I wrongly input the number i.e. 99999dfggdf9999.999, validation is fired. Now again I input correct number i.e. 9999.99 and then try to enter any number in between 9999, it won't allow me to input.

[image][image]

Comment: does it get disabled?

Comment: nope. it is enabled. It only allows if we delete numbers from right-hand side and reach to index where we want to enter

Comment: I am not able to understand and reproduce the problem can you provide the plunker?